# Kivy App crashes: "Not Responding"

Tags: python, visual-studio, python-2.7, kivy

I want to **make apps using kivy**. I installed **python 2.7** and **kivy 1.9.1**.

I used [this link](https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-windows.html) to install kivy.

And I am following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CYNWK2GpwgA) to make a **Hello World** app.

I am using Visual Studio 2015.

When I run the program, first, console shows up after that another black window shows up with the text "Hello World!". The problem is when I click the second black window, it **gets whiter** and says **"Not Responding"**. I also tried this for another Login app again using kivy. When I try to fill TextInput it again gets whiter and saying not responding so I cannot use my program.

[image]

Following is the code which crashes:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class SampleKivy(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text="Hello world")



SampleKivy().run()
```

I again installed kivy also using `pip install "Kivy-1.9.1+sdl2-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl"` command if there were installation problem in the previous link.

[In this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CYNWK2GpwgA) the guy does not have this problem, his windows seems good.

I can use Visual Studio for asp.net with no problem.

*(This code does not have that problem and no crash: `print "hello"` which makes me think that the problem is about kivy)*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try running the app with python idle.

Comment: Also post the error showing in the terminal

Comment: I run it with python idle, no longer crashing. But I cannot resize the window. And when I move the window with mouse, terminal prints `WindowsError: exception: access violation writing 0x0000000000000018
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "_ctypes/callbacks.c", line 313, in 'calling callback function'
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\kivy\input\providers\wm_touch.py", line 207, in _touch_wndProc
     lParam)` with many times

Comment: One more problem, when I run the Login sample which I mentioned in my question, in python idle, the app does not say "Not responding", but it does net let me type inside the TextInput, I cannot write it. [Login sample is here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cJtdb-vPxBo)

Comment: unfortunatly I dont have a windows machine to test this. Runs fine on linux. But googling this part "WindowsError: exception: access violation writing" might bring you closer to a solution

Comment: also is your python version 64bit or 32bit, vs the kivy

Comment: Python version is 64 bit. As I said I used two link to install kivy. [In first link I used](https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-windows.html#install-win-dist) I think 64 bit kivy is installed but I saw something like these ; `pypiwin32` , `compiler = mingw32` in installation page as you can see, maybe mingw32 causes this problem. After this problem I decided to install kivy again using [this link](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) and in here I am sure that kivy is 64 bit. Because I installed this one `Kivy-1.9.1+sdl2-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved finally. I was supposed to install Python 2.7.12 64-bit but my version was 2.7.0 64-bit. After changing python version, it worked! :)